# How does managed language ensure no segfault

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, unmanaged

As far as I know (correct me if I am wrong please), managed languages (or at least C#) is not going to make any `segfault` (at least when no `Unsafe` or directly dealing with `unmanaged memory`). This opposite to unmanaged language (or at least C++) where you can get `segfault` by just taking a look to cat near you for a second while coding.

**The question**: How managed language ensure this? were their runtime library built and tested so carefully. Or they have some way to catch these segfault and deal with it in a way or another?

The **motivation** behind this question: I have C# application that calls a native C++ library (both were built by me). When my C++ DLL makes segfault, the whole application goes down (some services go down) which is not a good thing at all. I know that when getting segfault, this means something was done wrongly and need to be corrected. However, at least I want some mechanism to solve this problem when the buggy (may cause segfault) C++ DLL is working on the customer machine.

Comment: If you use an "unsafe" DLL that can crash, then that crash will bring down your whole program, there's not really much you can do about it. What you *can* do is minimize the impact by separate the main program from the parts that uses the unsafe DLL. That way if the DLL crashes then your main program will still run, can detect that the crash has happened, and start up the failing program again. However, it's probably easier and quicker to find and fix the crash instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am totally with you that fixing the problem is the only logical solution. But I can not even take a log to know what happened.. the best log message I had is. "Something wrong with your program" :D

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Add internal logging and traces, write to your own log file. At least it could help narrow down the location if you can't use a debugger.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error?

Comment: You mean the one happend on some client machine or in general ?

Comment: Managed languages avoid segfaults by **not letting you do things that cause segfaults**.

Comment: If you check "borrow" in Rust and C++ 17's "ownership" you will see even native languages can achieve the same goal now.

Comment: @LexLi May you help me with some link plz

Comment: @HumamHelfawi the keywords are enough for Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They don't allow you to manually deallocate memory.
2. They don't enable you to read/write from/to arbitrary memory addresses (C++ also doesn't allow this, but the language syntax makes it possible).
3. (as a special form of the above) They check every array access whether it is within the bounds of the array
4. To the best of my knowledge, they don't have undefined bahavior (except of courese, when calling unsafe code)

> I want some mechanism to solve this problem when the buggy (may cause segfault) C++ DLL is working on the customer machine.

The problem is that even if you could allow your program to continue (I don't know if Windows/c# offer any mechanism to do this), it might no longer be in a valid state, so depending on what the error is and to what kind of ressources you program has access to, this might actually result in worse errors than just a program crash, including the destruction of userdata.

Comment: So in other words, they use defensive methodology and not catching this errors at all. They just made sure not to happen ?

Comment: In principle yes. However, you can still have e.g. a `nullReferenceException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException`, but contrary to a segfault, those can be caught by standard language constructs.

Comment: Yup those errors are so kind and friendly... Thanks for making it clear :)

Comment: Well I think the main advantage is, that you are guaranteed to get an error if you try to use an null reference or out-of-bounds index, which means, they are more likely to be found during testing and easier to fix. A segafault on the other hand is just one possible outcome of those violations in c++ (most often caused by dereferencing a nullptr, but even that is not guaranteed).

Comment: yes it is UB which may lead to segfault and may not which makes it worse